# Cloud Functions for Firebase with HTTP Triggers throws SSL Exception

Tags: android, ssl, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Cloud Functions for Firebase and have created consumable API endpoints for clients. The endpoints works great on Web and iOS clients, however, on Android, I get an SSL error with the following exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
```

I tried connecting the same using `openssl` from my terminal, and it failed with the following error:

**Command:**

```
openssl s_client -connect us-central1-android-clean-architectu-38a86.cloudfunctions.net:443
```

**Response:**

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
6233:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59.60.1/src/ssl/s23_lib.c:185:
```

My assumption is that Firebase could be using a self-signed server certificate, which is causing the "unknown certificate authority". According to the Android's SSL documentation, this can resolved by creating my own `TrustManager` and trusting the certificate. Although I haven't done this yet, I'm wondering if there's an alternate soultion that exists. (And yes, I could be wrong with my assumption)

Has anyone else faced this issue, and know why this is happening? Any soultion to this?

---

**EDIT**

As requested for steps to reproduce (the question was voted to close), here's how you can reproduce it

On Android, using any networking library (I'm using Loopj), make a `GET` request for the following API - `https://us-central1-android-clean-architectu-38a86.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld`

The response will result in a failure with `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer` exception. Android API 19, 22, 23 throws the exception, however, it works on Android API 25.

Assumption 2 - This could be a TLS 1.2 issue?

Comment: Cross-posted to https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/134

Comment: Just hit the same brick wall with FastSpring's webhooks. I also have reason to believe it may be related to the TLS version.